# Error: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit

Este error aparece cuando ejecuto la prueba. No sé cómo resolverlo gracias por su ayuda

> Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.SerenityRunner;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Managed;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Steps;
import pasos.pasoscorreo;

@RunWith(SerenityRunner.class)
public class testcorreo {

    @Managed(driver = "chrome", uniqueSession = true)
    WebDriver driver;

    @Steps
    pasoscorreo buyer;

    @Test 
    public void Ingresar_Gmail_Valida_Correo_NoLeido() throws     
    InterruptedException {

    buyer.Abrir_Gmail();
    buyer.Ingresar_usairio("Ingsisacontreras");
    buyer.Ingresar_password("fdfdfd;");
    buyer.Buscar_correo("Alejandro Rendon ");
    buyer.UsuarioCon_correo();
    buyer.Ultimo_correo();
    buyer.Descripcion_Correo();
    driver.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez necesitas un archivo *properties* para indicarle a serenity donde se encuentra el driver de Chrome.

El archivo `serenity.properties` se crea dentro de la carpeta `src/test/resources` y tiene el siguiente contenido:

```
# CHROME OPTIONS
webdriver.chrome.driver=webdrivers/chromedriver.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Tambien pasa cuando se tiene desactualizado el archivo chrome.exe  Se soluciona eliminandolo y ejecutando de nuevo para que se autodescargue la versión más reciente nuevamente.
También puede que tengas desactualizada la dependencia en el pom o build.gradle que tiene que ver con el driver

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

He tenido ese mismo error, esto se debe a que la descarga automática que realiza serenity del chromedriver es una versión antigua a la que tiene el navegador, esto se da porque la versión del driver aún no ha sido publicada por parte de chrome. Entonces lo primero que hice fue:

1.- Ir a la página de descargar del chrome driver y descargar la versión que indicaba el navegador "https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable".

2.- Ejecutar el proyecto para ubicar donde se encuentra alojado chromedriver.exe que serenity descargó de manera automática y reemplazar dicho chromedriver.exe con el que se descargó de la página Chrome for testing.

3.- Volver a ejecutar y con ello se soluciona el problema de que no inicie el navegador.

Nota: El problema es por que google chrome no publica la última versión estable del driver de donde serenity realiza la descarga automática.
Un ejemplo de lo que está pasando es:

1.- La descarga automática que realizar serenity del chromedirver.exe, lo realiza de está url "https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads", y esta url solo está publicada hasta la versión 114.0.5735.90 y la versión del navegador es superior.

2.- Para solucionar ello, tenemos que descargar manualmente la versión del chromedriver.exe que tiene tu navegador en "https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable".

3.- Buscamos la ruta donde se encuentra alojado el chromedrive.exe que se muestra en el log y reemplazamos por el que descargamos manualmente que tiene la versión actual del navegador. Ejecutamos y listo levanta el navegador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).